# 'Input string not in correct format' Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a DropDownList with values that I get from a SQL database. Depending on the selection made from the DropDownList, I populate a GridView, also from a SQL database.

When I set AutoPostBack=true on the DropDownList I get a 'Input string not in correct format' error.

My DropDownList:

```
<html>
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlClient" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsClientList"                        AppendDataBoundItems="True" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Name" TabIndex="0" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="11px" ForeColor="#2D2D2D" AutoPostBack="true">
        <asp:ListItem Value="">--- Select ---</asp:ListItem>
  </asp:DropDownList>
  <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="dsClientList" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetList" TypeName="Class.Client">
  </asp:ObjectDataSource>
</html>
```

In my ObjectDataSource for my GridView I use the following SelectParameters:

`<SelectParameters>
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlClient" Name="pClientID" PropertyName="SelectedValue"
Type="Int32" />
</SelectParameters>`

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set numeric column for `DataValueField="Name".` May be an `ID` or `Number`.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlClient" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsClientList"  
                     AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
                     DataTextField="Name" 
                     DataValueField="pCientID" 
.....
```

Comment: Thank you SO much! That worked perfectly, had to change it to ID instead of using Name.

Answer (score 3):

It is probably trying to convert the value of this list item to an `int`

```
<asp:ListItem Value="">--- Select ---</asp:ListItem>
```

An empty string cannot be converted to an integer, try using -1 or 0.

Comment: I tried using 0 but it still did the same ;/ I'm giving up on asp.net

Answer (score 0):

You can try by setting default value for `--- Select ---`, if you set blank `""` which can't parse to Int32, you might use below code block:

```
<html>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlClient" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsClientList"                        AppendDataBoundItems="True" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="yourClientIDField" TabIndex="0" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="11px" ForeColor="#2D2D2D" AutoPostBack="true">
    <asp:ListItem Value="0">--- Select ---</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="dsClientList" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetList" TypeName="Class.Client">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
</html>
```